# setcookie() sets $_COOKIE to zero at a first access to the page

Tags: php, cookies, browser, setcookie

I have this code in a php page:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    if(!setcookie($cookie_name, mt_rand(), time() + (86400 * 30), "/")) {
        die("[ERROR COOKIE] Failed to set cookie!");
    }
}
```

If I don't have any cookie set in my browser the first time the page is loaded `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` is set to `0`. Afterwards, if I reload the page, it is set to a random number as expected.

So far I just make a workaround like this:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    if(!setcookie($cookie_name, mt_rand(), time() + (86400 * 30), "/")) {
        die("[ERROR COOKIE] Failed to set cookie!");
    }
    if($_COOKIE[$cookie_name] == 0) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=./\" />";
        die();
    }
}
```

but what I'd like to understand is why the first time setcookie() defaults to `0`.

Comment: How are you inspecting it the first time? The `$_COOKIE` superglobal won't get the new value from `setcookie()` until after a reload. That is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. It defaults to `NULL`, because it hasn't been set.

`setcookie` merely adds the `Set-Cookie` header to the list of headers to be sent to the browser. It is a convenience shortcut for `header("Set-Cookie: ...");` that does the formatting for you. It *does not* modify the `$_COOKIE` superglobal.

You can, of course, do it yourself:

```
function updatecookie($name,$val,$exp=0,$path="/",$domain="",$secure=false,$httponly=false) {
    $ret = setcookie($name,$val,$exp,$path,$domain,$secure,$httponly);
    if( $ret) $_COOKIE[$name] = $val;
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that $_COOKIE[$name] was set after calling setcookie(), but now, thanks to your reply, I've understood that $_COOKIE[$name] gets the saved cookie from the browser.